# Is there any way to defer all scripts except for one?

Tags: javascript

Found this awesome code

```
function js_defer_attr( $tag ){
  // add defer to all  scripts tags
  return str_replace( ' src', ' defer="defer" src', $tag );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'js_defer_attr', 10 );
```

Is there any way to defer all scripts except for one?

I've been trying to use this but I believe it keeps deferring an onload script

Comment: I don't think changing the attribute can have an effect *after* a prior script tag already in the document has been parsed?